# Lazarus Assembler Error "00403BE0 833800 cmpl $0x0,(%eax)"

Tags: assembly, error-handling, lazarus

i am writing a Lazarus Application to compare different algorithms. I am loading the data to be sorted from a textfile into a memo box, select the sorting algorithm and a give the output to anothr memo box (memo2).

When I click on the "run"-button (Button 3) an assembler error pops up:
"External: SIGSEGV" at address 403BE0

00403BE0 833800                   cmpl   $0x0,(%eax)

here is my code:

```
    unit vgl_alg_unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  ActnList, Crt;

type
 RetArStr = AnsiString;
  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    ComboBox2: TComboBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    OpenDialog2: TOpenDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox2Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
    function BubbleSort: RetArStr;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  filename, sort1, sort2, s : string;
  dname : textfile;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
OpenDialog1.Filter := 'All Files|*.txt;';
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
     try
        memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(opendialog1.filename);
     except
       on E: EInOutError do
       writeln('Fehler aufgetreten. Details: ', E.Message);
     end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if OpenDialog2.Execute then
   begin
     filename := OpenDialog2.filename;
     ShowMessage(filename);
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
    0: sort1 := BubbleSort;
    1: sort1:='Heap Sort';
    2: sort1:='Insertion Sort';
    3: sort1:='Quick Sort';
    4: sort1:='Selection Sort';
    5: sort1:='Shaker Sort';
    6: sort1:='Shell Sort';
   end;
   case ComboBox2.ItemIndex of
    0: sort2:= BubbleSort;
    1: sort2:='Heap Sort';
    2: sort2:='Insertion Sort';
    3: sort2:='Quick Sort';
    4: sort2:='Selection Sort';
    5: sort2:='Shaker Sort';
    6: sort2:='Shell Sort';
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memo1.clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

function TForm1.BubbleSort : RetArStr;
var
  i,k,c,j: integer;
  temp : string;
  a: array of string;
begin
c := memo1.lines.count;
for j:=0 to c-1 do
  a[j] := memo1.lines[j];
for i:= (c-1) to 1 do
    for k:=0 to i-1 do
      if a[k] > a[k+1] then
          begin
            temp:= a[k+1];
            a[k+1] := a[k];
            a[k] := temp;
          end;
 memo2.clear;
 for k:= 0 to c-1 do
       begin
         memo2.lines.add(a[k]);
       end;
end ;

end.
```

Can somebody help me? I really don't know what to do...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In `function TForm1.BubbleSort : RetArStr;` open array `a: array of string;` is not initialized.  Call `SetLength` before any usage of it, `SetLength(a, c);` in your example.

Comment: @Abelisto: that's it! Problem is solved.